# String with unicode and UILabel with multiline

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, uilabel

I'm using `XMLDictionary` for save data from `xml` to `NSDictionary` and then I print `NSDictionary` I saw some code in unicode:

```
"text" = "Test \U2013 test\\nTest \U2013 test";
```

So when I use `UILabel` with multiline it print `test - test\nTest - test`

but I expected for:

```
            test - test
            Test - test
```

How I can make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading in xml characters can be interesting.  XML doesn't know that \ means "Special character comes next".  It knows that "\" means "I want you to write a "\".

So to get what you are looking for you are going to have to read in your string from the dictionary, then do a `[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\n" withString:@"\n"];` on it to get your carriage returns back.

You can save carriage returns in xml, but not using the "\" method.